# parallel bash commands with a certain delay in between

Tags: bash, shell

I am already familiar with sleep and usleep commands. But I am not sure how to use them for parallel commands which are supposed to have a certain delay with respect to the start time of the previous command. I mean something like this (commands 1 to n are supposed to be run in parallel with a delay between their start time):

```
Command 1's start time: 0
Command 2's start time: 0+d
Command 3's start time: 0+2d
.
.
.
Command n's start time: 0+(n-1)d
```

Comment: How many tasks are there? And what sort of delay are you envisaging?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're just running them in the background in the shell then you could simply have each loop sleep after starting its command.

```
for cmd in cmd1 cmd2 ... cmdN; do
    eval ${cmd} &
    sleep ${d}
done
```

Comment: Maybe ad a caveat that the commands should be wrapped in quotes to handle arguments and options. Alternatively execution could be achieved using `$(${cmd}) &` but this is less stylish.

Comment: @ShellFish Good point.  I typically write my bash answers lazily and then assume that Gilles or Stephane will wander by at some later date to correct it. :)

Comment: Is there a nice way of doing this if the commands are long and full of parameters and quote marks?